# React Navigation - remove title for one tab and oversize button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to create bottom tab navigation similar to the following in my app:

[image]

I have managed to use React Navigation to set up a TabNavigator with the options I need but I am having issues with two pieces:
1. How do I remove the title from only one of the tabs?
2. How do I oversize my middle tab icon to go outside of the main tab container? I can change the size but it does not go outside.

Here is what it looks like so far for me:
[image]

My code for that particular tab looks like this:

```
export const MainTabs = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
  Create: {
      screen: create,
      navigationOptions: {
        // title: 'Create',
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
          // <Image
          //   source={require('../assets/signUpButton.png')}
          //   style={[styles.icon, { tintColor }]}
          // />
          <Icon 
            name='plus-circle'
            color={tintColor} 
            size={75}
            type='font-awesome'
          />
        )
      },
      tabBarOptions: {
        showLabel: true
      }
    },
....
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Facing currently the same..